# Can use input only one time then it goes null

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing practice of JavaScript and now having problem in printing. If i write "listaa" to input field and press Submit button, it lists few words. Then I write something else and try "listaa" again, it is not working. I tried to first make it blank with `document.getElementById("listaus").innerHTML = ""` but it's not working.

Consolelog says `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null` and tell me it is line 42, where is the first document.getElementById in case you write "listaa".

How can I solve this?

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Laskin</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="/css/style.css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>

  <audio id="myAudio">
  <source src="americano.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>

  <div class="row">
    <div>Nimesi: <input type="text" id="kakki" name="kakki"/></div>  

    <button onclick="takki()">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="tulostusdiv">
  <span id="result1">
  <span id="listaus">
  </span>
  </div>
    <div class="tulostusdiv">
  <span id="result2">
    <a id="google" href=""></a>

  </span>
  </div>

  </body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/laskimenskripti.js"></script>

</html>
```

And JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("kakki").value
console.log(kakki.value)


var musiikki = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 


function takki(){
    let current ="kakki"

    var txt = ""
    let array = ['Google', 'joku', 'asdasd', 'asdasd']

    if (kakki.value == "moi"){
        document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = kakki.value
        document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = kakki.value
    }
    else if(kakki.value == "Pasi"){
        document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = "En tunne Pasia, mutta Matin tunnen."
    }
    else if(kakki.value == "Matti"){
        console.log("Matti ei ole paikalla")
    }
    else if(kakki.value == "Reiska"){
        var i;
        for (i = 1; i < 101; i++)
        console.log("Reijo" + [i]);
    }
    else if(kakki.value == "aloitamusiikki"){
        musiikki.play();
    }
    else if(kakki.value == "lopetamusiikki"){
        musiikki.pause();
    }
    else if(kakki.value == "google"){
        document.getElementById("google").innerHTML = "Siirrytäänkö Googleen?"
        document.getElementById("google").href = "https://www.w3schools.com";
        document.getElementById("google").target = "_blank";
    }
    else if(kakki.value == "listaa"){
        array.forEach(myFunction);
        document.getElementById("listaus").innerHTML = ""
        document.getElementById("listaus").innerHTML = txt;

        function myFunction(value, index, array) {
        txt = txt + value + "<br>"; 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The markup is invalid -> https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say this is the issue:

```
<span id="result1">
  <span id="listaus">
```

You are overriding #result1 before so #listaus does not exist afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. I removed span id listaus and changed `document.getElementById("listaus").innerHTML = ""
        document.getElementById("listaus").innerHTML = txt;` to `document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = ""
        document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = txt;` and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

You forgett an closing tag

```
<span id="result1">
<span id="listaus">
</span>
```

Try with

```
<span id="result1">
</span>
<span id="listaus">
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not logical

```
 document.getElementById("kakki").value
```

out of the function `takki()` , So insert it into the function

and Check all ends of tags like :

```
<span id="listaus">
```